# Google Analytics / DTM does not ingest the correct click url

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am a little new to combining GA/GTM. I have a setup with two external links on one page in the following order

1. foo.com/products
2. foo.com/products/best-ever

I am clicking on link 2. When I inspect the dataLayer variable in the console for the click event it seems to *intend* to send the correct url.

However in GTM debug we receive the the url as if link 1 was clicked.

Is there a reason why this occurs?

Comment: Add screenshot of debug, pls

Comment: What would you like to see in the screenshot? the information in the request? @MichelePisani

Comment: Variables value and their status